# pyobdc and direct query differ in Teradata

Tags: python, odbc, teradata, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to connect to a Teradata database and it seems that something is now working properly:

This:

```
conn = connect(params)
cur = conn.cursor()

if len(argv) > 1:
        query = ''.join(open(argv[1]).readlines())
else:
        query = "SELECT count(*) FROM my_table"

cur.execute(query)
print "...done"

print cur.fetchall()
```

returns what seems to be an overflow, a number like 140630114173190, but in fact there are only 260 entries in the table (which I do get by querying directly on the sql assistant from teradata)

However, when doing  a `select *` the result seems to be correct.

Any idea of what could be going on?

Running on:

```
Linux eron-redhat-100338 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64
```

Thanks

EDIT: I don't think this is a fetchall() issue. That's only gong to change whether I get a list, or a tuple or whatever but the number won't change.

Interestingly, I discovered that changing to

```
query = "SELECT CAST(count(*)) AS DECIMAL(10,2) FROM my_table"
```

does get the right number, only in as float number. Something is going on with the integers.

Comment: The `fetchall` method is supposed to return [all result rows as a sequence of sequences](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall), not a single scalar value. Can you post exactly what you're getting from `cur.fetchall()`?

Answer (score 0):

While `fetchall()` returns recordset, and you need 1st column of 1st record you should use something like:

```
print('# of rows: [%s]' % (c.fetchall()[0][0]))
```

or:

```
for row in c.fetchall():
    print('# of rows: [%s]' % (row[0]))
```